# App crashed when trying to change UITextView.text

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, uitextview

My app crashed when i trying to change `UITextView` text.

Here is the code: (header file):

```
//
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface DetailViewController : UIViewController {

    IBOutlet UIImageView *appImage;
    IBOutlet UILabel *appName;
    IBOutlet UILabel *appDeveloper;
    IBOutlet UILabel *appVersion;
    UIActivityIndicatorView *loading;
    IBOutlet UITextView *appAbout;
    NSString *selectedApp;

}

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *selectedApp;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIImageView *appImage;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UILabel *appName;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UILabel *appDeveloper;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UILabel *appVersion;
@property (nonatomic, retain) UIActivityIndicatorView *loading;
@property (nonatomic, retain) UITextView *appAbout;

@end
```

implementation file:

```
- (void)loadData {

    NSString *trimmedString = [selectedApp stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@"%20"];
    self.navigationItem.title = @"Info";
    NSLog(@"%@", trimmedString);
    NSString *website = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://shaymargolisapps.x10.mx/send.php?mission=GetNameOfApps&aname=%@", trimmedString]; 
    NSData *dataURL = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:website]];
    NSString *strResult = [[[NSString alloc] initWithData:dataURL encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]autorelease];
    appName.text = strResult;
    NSString *website1 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://shaymargolisapps.x10.mx/send.php?mission=GetDeveloperOfApp&aname=%@", trimmedString]; 
    NSData *dataURL1 = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:website1]];
    NSString *strResult1 = [[[NSString alloc] initWithData:dataURL1 encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]autorelease];
    appDeveloper.text = strResult1;
    NSString *website2 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://shaymargolisapps.x10.mx/send.php?mission=GetVersionOfApp&aname=%@", trimmedString]; 
    NSData *dataURL2 = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:website2]];
    NSString *strResult2 = [[[NSString alloc] initWithData:dataURL2 encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]autorelease];
    appVersion.text = strResult2;
    NSString *website3 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://shaymargolisapps.x10.mx/send.php?mission=GetInfoOfApp&aname=%@", trimmedString];
    NSData *dataURL3 = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:website3]];
    NSString *strResult3 = [[[NSString alloc] initWithData:dataURL3 encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]autorelease];
    NSLog(@"%@", strResult3);
    **appAbout.text = strResult3;**
    NSString *website4 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://shaymargolisapps.x10.mx/send.php?mission=GetImageOfApp&aname=%@", trimmedString];
    NSData *dataURL4 = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:website4]];
    NSString *strResult4 = [[[NSString alloc] initWithData:dataURL4 encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]autorelease];
    NSData* imageData = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:strResult4]];
    UIImage* image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:imageData];
    [appImage setImage:image];
    [image release];
    [imageData release];
    [UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = NO;
    [loading stopAnimating];
    [loading setHidden:YES];
    [appName setHidden:NO];
    [appDeveloper setHidden:NO];
    [appVersion setHidden:NO];
    [appImage setHidden:NO];
    [appAbout setHidden:NO];

}
```

My app crashed on `appAbout.text = strResult3;` line. What am I doing wrong?

loadData is called with `[self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(loadData) withObject:nil];` from `viewDidLoad`

(Xcode 4.4 DP2, iPhone Simulator 5.1, base SDK 4.3)

Comment: What is the error message from the crash?  Also, does your NSLog statement that outputs the content of strResult3 give the output you expect?

Comment: yes. NSLog give my expect output. CRASH ERROR MASSAGE:

Comment: `bool _WebTryThreadLock(bool), 0x6d9d7d0: Tried to obtain the web lock from a thread other than the main thread or the web thread. This may be a result of calling to UIKit from a secondary thread. Crashing now...
1   WebThreadLock
2   -[UITextView setText:]
3   -[DetailViewController loadData]
4   -[NSThread main]
5   __NSThread__main__
6   _pthread_start
7   thread_start`

Comment: Is `loadData` running on your main thread?  If so, are you interacting with `appAbout` at all in any background threads?  This error suggests that you might be ding so.  Keep in mind that all UI updating must be done only on the main thread.

Comment: loadData running with methamod `[self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(loadData) withObject:nil];` from viewDidLoad void.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You must not change UI* objects from a background thread. That has to be done from the main thread.

You could use gcd to perform the changes on the main thread. Something like this:

```
/* ... */
NSString *strResult4 = [[[NSString alloc] initWithData:dataURL4 encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]autorelease];
NSData* imageData = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:strResult4]];
UIImage* image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:imageData];

dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    self.navigationItem.title = @"Info";
    appName.text = strResult;
    appDeveloper.text = strResult1;
    appVersion.text = strResult2;
    appAbout.text = strResult3;
    [appImage setImage:image];
    [UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = NO;
    [loading stopAnimating];
    [loading setHidden:YES];
    [appName setHidden:NO];
    [appDeveloper setHidden:NO];
    [appVersion setHidden:NO];
    [appImage setHidden:NO];
    [appAbout setHidden:NO];
});

[image release];
[imageData release];
```